# Sending packet using libpcap speed limitation

Tags: c++, networking, packet-capture, libpcap, packet-injection

I wrote a program that captures Ethernet packets from some NIC (i.e eth0) at high speed (about 1Gbps) and forward traffic using `pcap_sendpacket()` to another NIC (i.e eth1).

While the forwarder Ethernet interface is not connected to another computer NIC, forwarding speed is desired, but when I connect it, sending speed gets down awfully (from 900 Mbps to 100 Mbps).

Can anybody explain the reason?

<sub>**OS**: Kubuntu linux 10.10

**Language**: C++

**Library**: Libpcap</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the destination NIC is a 100 Bbps interface :D :p

Answer (score 0):

Or the auto-negotiation for the network device has been turned off and is trying 100Mbps firstly.